# Hibernate could`t create query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following sql request:

```
    @Query("""
    SELECT ServiceCategory.name, (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Seat
        WHERE Seat.serviceCategory.id = ServiceCategory.id
        AND Seat.aircraft.tailNumber = :aircraftTailNumber
    ) AS Count FROM ServiceCategory
    """)
    Collection<?> countSeatsGroupByServiceCategory(String aircraftTailNumber);
```

My Entities:

ServiceCategory:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "service_category")
public class ServiceCategory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "rate")
    private double rate;
}
```

SeatEntity:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "seat")
public class Seat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private ServiceCategory serviceCategory;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Aircraft aircraft;

    @Column(name = "number_seat")
    private int numberSeat;
}
```

[image]

My Exception:

[image]

I don't understand why the error occurs.

Comment: Add all information as text not as images

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow you to insert more code

Comment: Add `@Entity` annotation on your `Aircraft` class

Comment: @AndreiLisa, it exists, it’s just that the screenshot was cropped that way

Comment: could you also share your project structure(packages) also the version of spring-boot that you are using. To do it faster i suggest to put in the code fragments that you provide also imports on classes and package.

Comment: COUNT(*) isn't a part of JPQL. You need to specify exactly what you are counting - maybe use Count(s) or count(s.id). You also cannot use ServiceCategory.name, or Seat.aircraft.tailNumber - JPQL queries are of the form "Select sc.name from FROM ServiceCategory sc"